# Javascript Redirect page to rewrite url not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Javascript Redirect page to rewrite url not work.

i use this code

```
<script language="JavaScript">window.location = 'test/6/loveyou';</script>
```

but when test it's will be redirect to

```
www.example.com/test.php?test_id=6&test_title=loveyou
```

i want to redirect to

```
www.example.com/test/6/loveyou
```

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /test.php?test_id=$1&test_title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Did you tried `location.replace` instead of `window.location` ?

Comment: your rewriterule is wrong `test=$1&test=$2` please check your parameter.